# How do you 'replace' numbers with 'x's' in jQuery with one button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know how to do replace multiple text by clicking a button with jQuery?

I've built a website that displays some text/data eg; "£100.00", but I what I need is to be able to 'replace' those monetary values with "£XXX.XX" with a **'Hide' button** like you get on some banking websites. For example one web page has:

£100.00, £200.00, £130.00 etc etc..

...so when a user presses the Hide button, all of the numbers on the page turn to £XXX.XX. Ideally, the button should then display "Show" instead of "Hide" and switch back when toggled.

This is for a static dummy site, so no data base.

I suspect this is best handled with jQuery?

Thanks for your time,

D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Case 1: Controlled Input

Assuming you can at least wrap all monetary values with something like this:

```
<span class="money-value">£200.00</span>
<span class="money-value">£300.50</span>
```

And that you can add button declared with:

```
<button id="secret-button">hide</button>
```

Then you could have some jQuery code doing this:

```
/**
 * Simple search and replace version.
 */
$(function() {
  $("#secret-button").click(function() {
    $(".money-value").html($(".money-value").html().replace(/[0-9]/g,"X"));
  });
});​
```

or a more advanced one with:

```
/**
 * Complet version.
 *
 * 1) on button click, if asking to hide:
 * 1.1) iterate over all entries, save their text, and replace it with markers
 * 1.2) toggle the button's text to "show"
 * 2) on button click, if asking to show:
 * 2.1) iterate over all entries, restore previous text
 * 2.2) clear the hidden store
 * 2.3) toggle the button's text to "hide"
 */
$(function() {
  var hiddenStore = [];

  $("#secret-button").click(function() {
      if ($(this).html() == "hide") {
        $(".money-value").each(function () {
           var text = $(this).html();

           hiddenStore.push(text);
           $(this).html(text.replace(/[0-9]/g,"X"));
        });
        $(this).html("show");
      } else {
        $(".money-value").each(function (i) {
           var text = hiddenStore[i];

           $(this).html(text);
        });
        hiddenStore = [];
        $(this).html("hide");          
      }
  });
});​
```

**Complete solution is here: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/u79FV/**

**Notes:**

- this *won't work* for input field values
- this assumes your text entries have been marked as shown above
- Does what you want with the button's changing state.
- Saves the values and puts them back.
- Meant to work even if new fields are added dynamically.
- [Shankar Sangoli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772055/shankarsangoli)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9262436/453590) uses a different way of saving the stored data, which you could as well consider (using the jQuery `.data()` method).
- you may want to switch the button to an `<input type="button" />` tag, in which case you'd use `.val()` instead of `.html()` to toggle its text.

## Case 2: Uncontrolled Input

Assuming you don't have control over where the values may show up, then you need to do something a bit more complicated, which is to look in the whole page for something that would look like a currency format. **I'd advise against it.**

But, the jQuery Highlight plugin could be something to look at, as its code does something similar (in that it searches for pieces of code to modify), and you could then reuse some of solution 1 to make it fit your purpose.

That would be harder to design in a fool-proof fashion though.

Comment: Yep I'll be wrapping them in a class. Thanks Heylem I'll look into this as well. ;-)

Comment: Haylem! thanks so much, this works perfectly! thanks for explaining this so clearly, much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
var expression = /\d{1}/g;
var newString = myString.replace(expression,"X");
```

Then just dump `newString` into whatever control you need it to appear in.

**Edit:**
A jQuery idea for something like this would be to give all of the controls that have these numbers a common class identifier to make them easy to grab with the selector:

```
$(".numbers").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\d{1}/g, "X"));
}
```

... more readable ...

```
$(".numbers").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var newText = text.replace(/\d{1}/g, "X");
    $(this).text(newText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Joel, I'll give this a go & let you know. ;-)

Comment: @Darren: This will help with the initial replacement, but I'd really recommend an amalgam of this usage of the `data` attributes as mentioned in the answer from Evan in order to achieve a viable toggling mechanism.

Comment: `/\d{1}/` is the same as just `/\d/`

Comment: @thg435: True enough. It's just my habit to write my expressions as specific as my intention.

Answer (score 1):

If your markup is something like this you can try this.

```
<span>£1000.00</span><span class="showhide">Hide</span>
```

JS

```
$('.showhide').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $prev = $this.prev();
    if(!$prev.data('originalvalue')){
        $prev.data('originalvalue', $prev.text());
    }
    if($this.text() == 'Hide'){
       $this.prev().text($prev.data('originalvalue').replace(/\d{1}/g,"X"));
       $this.text('Show');
    }
    else{
       $prev.text($prev.data('originalvalue'));
       $this.text('Hide');
    }
});
```

In the above code I am basically storing the original value using jQuery data method within the span element itself which is used to display the actual value.

Once you click on `Hide`, get the previous span using `prev()` method and set its text with original value replacing all the numbers in it by `X`. Then change the link text from `Hide` to `Show`.

Next when you click on `Show` get the previous span using `prev()` method and set its text with the original value and change the link text from `Show` to `Hide`.

References: **[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)**

Comment: @Darren - Take a look at this. Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: I like the usage of the `.data()`, however using `.prev` I don't think `.prev()` is what the OP was after.

Comment: @haylem - We don't know OP's mark so I gave an example. If the markup is different offcourse selector has to be different.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: yes, but he mentioned (or at least that's how I understood it) that he wanted multiple values replaced. I just think .prev makes it actually harder to understand and more confusing here; though perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(){
    var saveText = $('body').text();

    $(this).data('oldText', saveText);

    if ($(this).text() == "Hide"){
        $('body').text($('body').text().replace(/\d{1}/, "X"));
        $(this).text('Show');
    }
    else{
        $('body').text($(this).data('oldText'));
        $(this).text('Hide');
    }
});
```

This is kind of a complicated problem actually. You will need to be able to save the state of the text when its in number form so you will be able to toggle back and forth. The above code is untested but hopefully it will give you an idea what you need to do.

Comment: +1: In my own response I completely forgot about the request for a toggle.

Comment: Thanks for this Evan, but an error is showing on this line? "$('body').text($(this.data('oldText');

Comment: ...should it be this!?  $('body').text($(this.data('oldText')));

Comment: yeah good catch. should be $('body').text($(this).data('oldText'));

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleMoney() {
    $('.money').each(function() {
        var $$ = $(this), t = $$.text();
        $$.text($$.data('t') || t.replace(/\d/g, 'X')).data('t', t);
    });
    $('#toggleButton').text($('.money').text().match(/\d/) ? 'hide' : 'show');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DF88B/2/

Comment: Thanks, that switches the numbers, but doesn't change the text in the button from 'show' to 'hide'. I suspect that functionality will add to the code?

Comment: @Darren: sorry, the free hour is over.